# Special property of a particular type of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&t\\ 0&0&-t&0\\ 0&t&0&0\\ -t&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ where $t$ is real. Is there any special property for this matrix except having pure imaginary eigenvalues?

Comment: $A$ is skew-symmetric (i.e., $A^{\top}=-A$) and satisfies $A^2=-t^2 I$. I can also see that this matrix is associated with a matrix representation of the quaternion, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations) for instance.

Comment: It might be useful to note that $A$ can be expressed in nicely in terms of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):
$$
A = t \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} \otimes \pmatrix{0&1\\-1 & 0}.
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations